# creating shortcut windows files from ubuntu

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, samba

I am accessing my windows share from my ubuntu machine. I have installed samba. I am doing some automation for which I need to create .lnk files in this share.

Is it possible to create shortcuts from ubuntu ??

I can access the link address using "string .lnk" but not able to create one.

or is there any other way to create shortcuts??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create x-ms-shortcut,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

source = '/home/dell/Downloads/filename.exe'
destination = '/home/dell/Downloads/filename.lnk'

os.symlink(source, destination)

print "symlink created"
```

And the one below to create x-ms-dos-executable, (remember that here source is in Downloads and Destination is Documents)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

source = '/home/dell/Downloads/filename.exe'
destination = '/home/dell/Documents/filename.exe'

os.symlink(source, destination)

print "symlink created"
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Regards,
Md. Mohsin

Comment: Nope it doesnt. i already have tried this. i am creating shortcuts on windows shares from ubuntu.

Comment: @mrutyunjay, I tried it myself and it works for me.
I am on Linux Mint - sharing a window NTFS Drive.

What exactly did you try, what error did you get? And to avoid confusion, when you say "creating shortcuts on windows shares from ubuntu" -- what is your current/active OS? I am assuming it is Ubuntu, let me know if I am wrong

Comment: I am getting error "OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported" . I am using ubuntu12.04 and using samba to access windows shares.  :-(

Comment: @mrutyunjay right, this may not work on samba share. Try it on ext2.
And Just curious -- what type is your windows partition? NTFS/FAT?

Answer (score 0):

There is always the hard way, which is to reimplement Microsoft's link generation which is documented in
http://www.i2s-lab.com/Papers/The_Windows_Shortcut_File_Format.pdf